# Heroku - how to save state

Tags: java, tomcat, heroku

I noticed that if there's no activity on the server for a while it shuts down and starts again when there's new activity, thus any previous states are gone.

For example, I have a list of connected users with the username they entered, and the list is emptied if there's no activity for a while.

What is the recommended way to save states on Heroku?

Would serializing the state to a file every few minutes work? Do I even have write access on Heroku?

Comment: Serializing to a file will not work because the Heroku filesystem is [ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). This is good, because it ensures consistency in how your app runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTTP server should be stateless--anything important should be stored somewhere else, such as a database.

Comment: Where would the database be? Also, I think that an sql database or something similar is an overkill for that small server, so is it possible to place the data in a file on the server?

Comment: @kuhaku You'd bind it to your instance; Heroku has dozens of such services available. And you should expect your server to be destroyed and recreated from scratch at any time.

Comment: If you need to store a document (like you mentioned a file) you could use a [NoSQL database](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/mongolab). But it's not overkill. If you have important state, it needs to go in a database.

Comment: I just never worked with databases before, so I'd like to avoid the learning curve. @codefinger

Comment: If you store state local to a process (i.e. not in a database), then you can't scale (each process will have their own state), you can't restart, and you're app had better not crash :)

Comment: @kuhaku A dyno is the concrete Heroku implementation of a more generic "process" (meaning, for example, an instance of a server).